# Changing export of jpeg image from sheet to chart name

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have found a code in VBA that exports all of the charts in a workbook into a specified folder. It saves using the sheet name, but I would like it save using the chart name instead.

I tried

```
cht.Chart.Export "C:\Users\----\Desktop\ExcelCharts\" & Range("A1").Value & ".jpg", "JPG"
```

This code produced only one file, but had the name I wanted

```
cht.Chart.Export "C:\Users\----\Desktop\ExcelCharts\" & cht.Name & ".jpg", "JPG"
```

This code produced image 1 and image 10, while my charts are named Hydralaz 20 in sheet 1 and Hydralaz 10 in sheet 2.

The following is the script that successfully exports all charts in a workbook.

```
Sub Test()

Dim sht As Worksheet, cht As ChartObject
Dim x As Integer

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        x = 1
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            cht.Chart.Export "C:\Users\----\Desktop\ExcelCharts\" & sht.Name & ".jpg", "JPG"
            x = x + 1
        Next cht

    Next sht

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `sht.Name` to `cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text`